# Find the area of the region determined by the system: \begin{align} y & \ge |x| \\ y & \le -|x+1| +4 \\ \end{align}

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, area

> Find the area of the region determined by the system: \begin{align} y
>  & \ge |x| \\ y & \le -|x+1| +4 \\ \end{align}

**My attempt**

- Assuming $x>0$

I have the system 
$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
y &\ge x \\
y & \le -x+3 \\
\end{align}\end{cases}$$

- Assuming $x<0$

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
y &\ge -x \\
y & \le x+5 \\
\end{align}\end{cases}$$

A relevant interval is $-1<x<0$ because in this interval $y \le -|x+1| +4 $ is still positive while $y \ge |x|$ is negative.

How do I combine now this information to solve the problem ?

I don't see how I can  get something of the form $y \ge a$ and $y \le b$ which give clear bounds about  area... in this problem it seems more complicated.

Comment: I apologize if that's not a big of attempt but I am really clueless about what to do next.

Comment: Can you use graphs to solve it? Or do you have to solve it using algebraic way?

Comment: @KittyL I guess so,in my book there are several diagrams provided for these kind of problems.

Comment: @KittyL yes,I can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use graphs, then draw the graphs of the functions. The graph of $y=|x|$ is a pretty basic one. You can use transformation to get the graph of the other one. The following is the resulting picture:

[image]

You can see that it forms a rectangle. Can you proceed from here?

By the way, if you use algebraic way, you have to discuss three cases:
$$x\leq-1\\
-1\leq x \leq 0\\
x\geq 0$$

Comment: @Mr.Y: Sorry, did the transformation incorrectly. Just edited.

Answer (score 1):

For $x > 0$, your area is the area enclosed by the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = -x + 3$ between $0$ and their intersection point. Thus, determine $x = -x +3$ which gets you $2x = 3 \Leftrightarrow x = {3\over 2}$ . So the first area is 
$$\int_{0}^{3 \over 2} 2x - 3 dx$$

Process for $x < 0$ analogously.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:You have 4 equations of form $y=mx+c$ so find $4$ points of intersection $2$ each with opposite slopes also its a polygon with $2$ pair of lines parallel . Can you proceed further.